# When Web API 2.0 infrastructure populates Session values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

My Web API (2.0) services and MVC (4.0) code is running inside same web application. I call Web APIs from MVC application as usual HTTP service call.

I have added `IAuthenticationFilter` in the WebApi pipeline because I want to do some security related validations before any Web Api controller is executed. I keep  security related data (E.g. TokenId) in the `HttpContext.Current.Session`. E.g. `HttpContext.Current.Session["TokenId"]`.

Somehow data kept in the `Session` is available when I access it from MVC controller or from WebApi controller. But it's **NOT available in the `AuthenticationFilter` when filter runs for the first time** i.e. when very first WebApi call is done from MVC application.

Can you tell me when `Session` is populated by WebApi infrastructure and why values stored in the Session are unavailable during first call ? Note that they are *available* from the second call onwards!

I have already verified that `Session` has values in it. Its just that they are not available in the filter during it's first execution.

`SessionStateBehavior.Required` is already set correctly from WebApi from Global.asax.

(I know that Session is not recommended but I have to use it for now.)

Comment: I think that the main problem that you're experiencing is that action filters are cached, so you have to rely on the variables passed into them, that's why everyone is recommending the `filterContext`, but that's from MVC.

Comment: Do you use any DI container?  I reckon that you could inject your session into the constructor of your action filter...

Answer (score 1):

Try with this snippet in global.ascx.cs (mine is in VB but just translate the code)

```
Protected Sub Application_BeginRequest()
    if IsWebApiRequest() Then
        HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required)
    end if
end sub

Private function IsWebApiRequest() as Boolean
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Contains("api")
end function
```

For me it works and makes the session available in the AuthenticationFilter